# json object is not effecting to view

Tags: html, angular, formio

I am using angular Formio for dynamic screen creation, as part of that when I get the screen script from database, if I change the label of the particular element in `ngOnInit()` I am able to change.

but once the screen is displayed, then if I change the lable it is not effecting.

**html**

```
<Formio [form]="form" [submission]="submission" (submit)="onSubmit($event)"></formio>
<div class="mb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mb-5">
        <div class="pull-right" style="float:right;">
          <button class="btn save-button" (click)="clearData()">Clear data</button>
          <button class="btn save-button" (click)="showData()">Show data</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    this.triggerRefresh = new EventEmitter();
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/angcomp/3')
    .subscribe(
      response  => {
        debugger;
        this.data = response.json();
        this.form = this.data;
        this.form.components[0].label = 'Changed';//it is updating the lable in view
      },
        err => {console.error(err)}
    ); 

}


showData() {

    this.form.components[0].label = 'Again Changed'; // here it is not changing but in this.form.components[0].label value is displaying as 'Again Changed', but not effecting in front end
}
```

Comment: This seems like you have a problem with a third-party vendor. Have you read their documentation? You might have more luck raising an issue on their github if you have a genuine problem you can't find a solution for.

Comment: https://github.com/formio/angular-formio/wiki/Form-Renderer#updating-forms-and-submissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the refresh property in formio

In yout HTML:

```
<Formio [refresh]="triggerRefresh" [form]="form" [submission]="submission" (submit)="onSubmit($event)"></formio>
```

In your component:

```
showData() {
    this.form.components[0].label = 'Again Changed';
    this.triggerRefresh.emit({
    form: this.form
});
}
```

https://github.com/formio/angular-formio/wiki/Form-Renderer#updating-forms-and-submissions

Comment: And this you tried befor? <Formio [refresh]="triggerRefresh" [form]="form" [submission]="submission" (submit)="onSubmit($event)"></formio>                                                                                            this.triggerRefresh.emit();

Comment: it is worked for me with `[refresh]` but in the emit we need to update the form like `form: this.form`

Comment: Nice, yeah I don't know formio exactly