# How to refresh a form after submission and get a new form ID without refreshing entire window using Form.io

Tags: angular, formio, angular-formio

I have an Angular app. I am using Form.io and the form renderer to display this form in my app. I want to refresh the form after it has been submitted (redraw the form with the the same data in the fields but a new ID for the form). I can't assign an ID manually.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I see that there is a refresh attribute that accepts an event emitter (ex. [refresh]="refreshForm") but I can't figure out how to actually refresh the form and get a new ID without refreshing the entire window. That defeats the purpose of a single page application.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/formio/angular/issues/555

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736378/json-object-is-not-effecting-to-view